# jQuery Div Not hiding after Ajax Post

Tags: jquery, ajax, hide, show-hide

Here's the code:

```
$('div#listing').slideUp(function(){
    $('div#img_loading').show(); //THIS WORKS
});

var jqxhr = $.post("process.php", {page: 1},
    function(data) {
        //some code
    });

jqxhr.complete(function(){
    $('div#img_loading').hide(function(){ //THIS HIDE FUNCTION DOES NOT WORK
        $('div#listing').slideDown(); //THIS LINE WORKS
    });
});
```

The image successfully loaded but it does not hide itself after the ajax complete. Weird thing is the $('div#listing').slideDown() works, but the hide() does not.

Thanks so much!

Comment: i have same problem hide button works fine before ajax request,but if i click it after ajax call hide is  not working

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want a function inside your hide command

```
$('div#listing').slideUp(function(){
    $('div#img_loading').show(); //THIS WORKS
});

var jqxhr = $.post("process.php", {page: 1},
    function(data) {
        //some code
    });

jqxhr.complete(function(){
    $('div#img_loading').hide();
    $('div#listing').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: yes. did that already. but the effect is till the same. i put the slideDown function inside hide() so im sure that the content will show up after hiding the image

Answer (score 0):

Please read through the [specifications](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) of the `hide` jQuery API. In your code, you are *trying to* specify a callback, which you need not. Just use this as is:

```
$('div#img_loading').hide();
```

EDIT:
Alternatively, you can just put the code above inside the ajax callback function:

```
var jqxhr = $.post("process.php", {page: 1},
    function(data) {
        //some code
        $('div#img_loading').hide();
    });
```

Comment: well, how to be sure that the image will load once the ajax is complete?

Comment: Show us some html and probably that'll help.